# Access on create variables through out the android activity class

Tags: java, android

I am getting `transaction_amount` variable from `getIntent()` in OnCreate method.

```
String transaction_amount = getIntent().getStringExtra("transaction_amount");
```

I want to access this variable outside of the OnCreate method.
Something like,

```
public class PayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String transaction_amount = getIntent().getStringExtra("transaction_amount");
    }

    protected void my_function(){
        // I want transaction_amount here.....
    }
}
```

Comment: you can call getIntent from everywhere unless this activity was started by an intent. an activity can created without intent. so best practice is to check it is null or not, then using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable :

```
public class PayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String value;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        value = getIntent().getStringExtra("transaction_amount");
    }
    public void yourFunction() {
        // You can acces value here
    }

// your activity here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create the transaction_amount variable as a class variable, then initialize it in the onCreate

```
public class PayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String transaction_amount;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      transaction_amount = getIntent().getStringExtra("transaction_amount");
}

protected void my_function(){
    // I want transaction_amount here.....
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

maintain transaction amount as a global variable ,if you require that variable in whole class or if you want acces that variable in method, send that variable as a parameter to that function and called that function from oncreate.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable and intialize it to the transactionamount in onCreate. Then use that global variable anywhere.

```
  public class PayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   String s; 

   @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    s = getIntent().getStringExtra("transaction_amount"); 
  }

  void anyFunction() {
   // use the string s here now

   }

  }
```